# Quiet reference notation in Jade?

Tags: express, pug

I was wondering whether Jade has an equivalent shorthand syntax like `$!variable_name` in Velocity? `$!variable_name` is the quiet reference notation of velocity which means that when `variable_name` has a value, then the value is used and when the `variable_name` is `null`, nothing happens. Is there a similar shorthand notation available in Jade?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade's standard `=` operator does this.  It outputs empty string as opposed to `"null"` or throwing an error.

```
printf "-var bar = null\np para1\n=bar\np para2" | jade
<p>para1</p><p>para2</p>
```

And just incase that printf line isn't clear, it would look like this in a file.

```
- var bar = null
p para1
= bar
p para2
```

Note however that this does NOT ignore undefined variables.  The variable must exist, but it can be null or empty string.  If it does not exist in the namespace of the template, jade will raise an error.  To do that you'd need something like

```
- var bar = bar || null
```